# Sed + replacing the content after specific syntax

Tags: bash, sed, redhat

we try to replace the content of the third field that comes after group word ,

the following line in file is always with the same syntax except third field that change

```
"groups": [{"group": "string”}],
```

The third field contains any characters of combination of  `A-Z` , `a-z` , numbers , ( `_   -  .` )

The third field is always in double quotes

Example

```
"groups": [{"group": "MOVIES.ARE.GOOD”}],

"groups": [{"group": "no_one.ok”}],

"groups": [{"group": "evry_one.lol”}],

"groups": [{"group": "NO_VALUES_ARE-GOOD”}],

"groups": [{"group": "___scripts”}],
```

etc

I try with the following sed  , but without success

```
var=my.word__that.I.need.to.replace
sed  -i "s/\(group\": \"\)[*]*/\1$var/"  file
```

Comment: Is this JSON data? If so, you'd be much better off using a tool intended to edit JSON (like `jq`). Also, your current pattern looks like it's trying to match the second field ("group"), not the first one ("group**s**"); is this intended? Finally, is that close quote after the third field actually a fancy unicode quote (`”`), or a plain ASCII quote (`"`).

Comment: it is not json , just look like json

Comment: You will never match with `sed`. Your last `'"'` is not ASCII 0x22, but some web `&rdquo;` multi-byte character `'”'`. You first need to address that -- then it will make your ability to match with `sed` much easier, e.g. `sed 's/["][^"]*["]/"'$var'"/3'`

Comment: The final closing quote is the multibyte character sequence `e2 80 9d` which is exactly the `&rdquo;` character [UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- all quotes are `"`.  See the comment from @Gordon above.
- you want to replace the 3rd field in each line.
- the replacement value is stored in a variable.
- I tested my command on this file content (filename data.txt):

  ```
  "groups": [{"group": "MOVIES.ARE.GOOD”}],  

  "groups": [{"group": "no_one.ok”}],

  "groups": [{"group": "evry_one.lol”}],

  "groups": [{"group": "NO_VALUES_ARE-GOOD”}],

  "groups": [{"group": "___scripts”}],
  ```

This works for me:

```
newword=TATA
sed -i "s/\(group\": \"\).*/\1$newword\"\}\],/"  data.txt
```

Basically, everything that follows `group": "` is replaced by `TATA"}],`

---

My result file now contains:

```
"groups": [{"group": "TATA"}],

"groups": [{"group": "TATA"}],

"groups": [{"group": "TATA"}],

"groups": [{"group": "TATA"}],

"groups": [{"group": "TATA"}],
```